# Where error? code write "Headers already send" and link on this code

Tags: header, header-files

IF i use this code i see warning "Headers already send" and link on this code. Other codes not worked.
But if i use one **li** facebook, or i use two **li** (twitter and vkontakte) all worked and i dont see warning, but if i use 3 **li** (twitter, vkontakte and facebook) i see warning...

Where error?

```
<li class="ssItem twitter"><a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=Скрипт анонимных вопросов - <?php echo "http://www.".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" onclick="window.open('http://twitter.com/home?status=Скрипт анонимных вопросов - <?php echo "http://www.".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>', 'Twitter', 'width=626, height=436'); return false;" title="Нажми, чтобы опубликовать в Twitter!" target="_blank">Публиковать в Twitter</a></li>

<li class="ssItem vkontakte"><a href="http://vkontakte.ru/share.php?url=<?php echo "http://www.".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" rel="nofollow" onclick="window.open('http://vkontakte.ru/share.php?url=<?php echo "http://www.".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>', 'Vkontakte', 'width=626, height=436'); return false;" title="Нажми, чтобы опубликовать в Vkontakte!" target="_blank">Публиковать в Vkontakte</a></li>

<li class="ssItem facebook"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=Скрипт анонимных вопросов&p[summary]=Создание скрипта анонимных вопросов&p[url]=<?php echo "http://www.".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" onclick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=Скрипт анонимных вопросов&p[summary]=Создание скрипта анонимных вопросов&p[url]=<?php echo "http://www.".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>', 'Facebook', 'width=626, height=436'); return false;" target="_blank" title="Нажми, чтобы опубликовать в Facebook!">Публиковать в Facebook</a></li>
```